# Windows dimensions

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi

Where can I find a document that describe the windows dimensions, like:

- Screen area (for each screen).
- Desktop area (for each screen).
- Desktop area without the task bar.
- Available area to position my application.
- etc.

Comment: I can't find what I want! may be I don't know a title to search!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx, ......

Comment: is there any document that describe each region and it's name: like where is the window area, client area ...

Comment: Too many questions. I'm particularly struggling to answer the *etc* bullet point. You need to read a book rather than asking us to write one for you.

Comment: I'm so sorry, just name a book for me and I will go. I don't know and microsoft naming is not that easy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following MSDN resources explain the different questions you are having:

- Window-related terminology and areas: [About Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632597.aspx)
- Relations between screen and window coordinates: [Window Coordinate System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145205.aspx)
- Relations between desktop and screen coordinates: [The Virtual Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145136.aspx)
- Retrieving screen metrics: [Multiple Monitor System Metrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162729.aspx)
- Window positioning across multiple displays: [Positioning Objects on Multiple Display Monitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162827.aspx)

Comment: I'd also recommend the [multiple monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation and the list of [system parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @arx Valuable links, I have updated the answer to include those as well.